# coffee-script npm install permissions screwed up

Tags: permissions, coffeescript, installation, npm

I tried to install coffeescript following the website's instructions:
`sudo npm install -g coffee-script`

This didn't work for some reason (it says command --`coffee`-- not found), and when I `ls -al /usr/local/bin` I get:

```
ls: /usr/local/bin/coffee: Permission denied
lrwx------    1 root     admin        44 Feb  2 00:00 coffee@
```

So it *is* in my path, it's just not permitted to my user? I thought it was the `-g` global flag, but reinstalling without it did nothing, even after trying to uninstall first (tried both...). I'm wondering why it (and `cake`, which looks similar) are under root instead of my user and why they are the only two that say permission denied.

The command ***does*** work under `sudo` -- ie. `sudo coffee` (and doesn't say *permission denied* for `sudo ls -al /usr/local/bin`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to `sudo npm uninstall -g coffee-script` and rerunning the install from non-sudo (why this didn't work the first time, I'm not sure - maybe the node-lib folders and things needed sudo to be created, but the scripts needed user modes?) YMMV.